# How to Get-Inhibit the WebSphere MQ Queue?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

There is a property for WebSphere MQ queue to inhibit `GET` from the queue.
To set this property I found two ways.

1. Just set the property using WebSphere MQ Explorer GUI.
2. Alter the queue with the MQSC command `ALTER QLOCAL(TEST) GET(DISABLED)`.

Is there any way to enable or disable `GET` on a WebSphere MQ queue through a Java Program?

Answer (score 3):

You can use PCF [Change, Copy, and Create Queue](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086990_.htm) command to change the attributes of the queue. This can be used from Java with the aid of the PCF Java helper classes, see [Handling PCF Messages with IBM MQ classes for Java](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030980_.htm)

**InhibitGet (MQCFIN)**

Get operations are allowed or inhibited (parameter identifier: MQIA_INHIBIT_GET ).

The value can be:

MQQA_GET_ALLOWED

Get operations are allowed.

MQQA_GET_INHIBITED

Get operations are inhibited.

Comment: Good inputs for fresh start... I am little bit new to PCF... i will do some work on those pcf comamnds then i will post my view on this.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  When you open the queue for `GET` or for `PUT` you can include the `SET` option and then use the `MQSET` API call.

- [`MQOpen` options](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026000_.htm?lang=en)
- [Open options for setting attributes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026050_.htm?lang=en)
- [Setting queue attributes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026780_.htm?lang=en)

Comment: Good inputs for fresh start... I am little bit new to PCF... i will do some work on those pcf comamnds then i will post my view on this.