# ibm WebSphere MQ pausing the queue through java api

Tags: ibm-mq

I need to pause the receiver queue some time (for process the already received messages)  in ibm websphere queue through the ibm java api.

Comment: pls refer this before posting your query http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for the In convinence:
My goal is 
1. I am keep on reading the messages fro the queues
2. in some point I need to pause the queue 
3. and need to manipulate those messages
4. and again need to resume the receving process from the queues

question is:
how can i pause the queue without stopping the queue manager.

Comment: Which WebSphere (traditional or liberty) and which version using which messaging provider?  Sounds like you want to "pause" the listeners used to feed messages to MDBs, right?

Comment: I am about  " IBM WebSphere MQ 7.5" 
Version:     7.5.0.6

Comment: WebSphere traditional or Liberty and (which version) ?

Comment: Basically I dont know what type of thing I have, from "dspmqver"
i came to know only below things
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.5.0.6
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     No
MaxCmdLevel: 750
LicenseType: Developer

Comment: I was asking "which type of WebSphere Application Server are you using?"  Liberty or traditional or which version.    I'm starting to wonder if you're even running in WebSphere Application Server though.

Comment: type : Traditional ; version: 7.5.0.6 ;

Comment: Yes , I want to delay(wait) for some time till another process trigger to start the queue. is there any command we have to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop Applications from being able to get messages from a Queue you can inhibit the Queue by setting the `GET` attribute on the Queue to `DISABLED`. This will still allow applications to put messages to the Queue but no applications will be able to get messages from the Queue. IF you want to stop messages from being able to be put to a queue you can do this by setting the `PUT` attribute to `DISABLED`.

When you're ready for the applications to be able to get messages from the Queue again you set the `GET` attribute to `ENABLED` and applications will be able to get messages from the Queue.

example MQSC command to set `GET` to `DISABLED`

> ALTER QLOCAL('') GET(DISABLED)

Be warned: If you inhibit the put or get on a Queue, applications attempting to put or get messages on that Queue will receive an error return code of `MQRC_PUT_INHIBITED` or `MQRC_GET_INHIBITED`. If you don't anticipate this your applications could fail.

Comment: Thanks @Rob  is there we can achieve the same "ALTER QLOCAL('') GET(DISABLED)" with any of the Java API . so I can call the same thing from Java application.

Comment: @Fresher  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233976/how-to-get-inhibit-the-websphere-mq-queue

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have find the logic to pause the queue but i have some other issues when implement them . Can you please provide any suggestion on that  code
http://stackoverflow.com/q/42360699/7529212.