# How to clear the issue "com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2040"

Tags: ibm-mq

I have used the below code to inhibit the queue but when I try to inhibit I got the error.
I have tried various open options for the particular queue but still i have the issue. what else i missed in my code;

```
     public void control(String mgrName, String queueName, int openOptions, string option)throws MQException{
     qMgr = new MQQueueManager(mgrName);
       mqQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);    
       if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
            System.out.println("Stop mesage received");
             mqQueue.setInhibitGet(MQC.MQQA_GET_INHIBITED);
             System.out.println("Queue inhibitted successfully");
        }else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("start")){
            System.out.println("Start mesage received");
            mqQueue.setInhibitGet(MQC.MQQA_GET_ALLOWED);
            System.out.println("Queue get allowed successfully");
        }
}
```

I have got the below Error when call this method.
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2040 = MQRC_NOT_OPEN_FOR_SET.  The IBM v7.5 Knowledge center page "[2040 (07F8) (RC2040): MQRC_NOT_OPEN_FOR_SET](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041110_.htm)" describes the reason for this error:

> **Explanation**
>
> An MQSET call was issued to set queue attributes, but the queue had not been opened for set.
>
> **Programmer response**
>
> Specify MQOO_SET when the object is opened.

If the `openOptions` passed to `control` included `MQOO_SET` then the error should go away.

Example below:

```
int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQConstants.MQOO_SET
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh , I have used old version of jar . that Only has the MQC interface constant. I have find the MQOO_SET constant value as 64. and directly hard coded that so it has worked as expected. thanks for the example. (I have already visit that site but i cant find that MQOO_SET, once again thanks for notify  the MQConstants)

Comment: what is the use of MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING

Comment: @Fresher, what version of jar files are you using?  Any MQ version prior to v7.1 and it's associated jar files are out of support.  7.1 goes out of support on April 30 2017.   The sample `MQSample.java` pulls the MQConstans from `import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants`.

Comment: @Fresher `MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING` is documented in the MQ 7.5 Knowledge center page "[MQOPEN - Open object](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q101870_.htm#q101870___FAIL_IF_QUIESCING)" as `The MQOPEN call fails if the queue manager is in quiescing state.`  Quiescing = shutting down.